# Vertically and horizontally aligned glosses using CSS after or elements for positioning

Tags: html, css, css-position

I currently have word glosses in flowing paragraph text that come from a data attribute and are presented after the word, e.g.:

```
.tcrobe-word.tcrobe-gloss::after {
  content: ' ('attr(data-tcrobe-gloss) ')';
  vertical-align: 10%;
}
...
<span class="tcrobe-word tcrobe-gloss" data-tcrobe-gloss="go">前往</span>
```

Which gives the following (1):

[image: inline glosses]

I would like users to also be able to have the glosses above (or below) with the following the behaviour when the glosses are wider than the original text (2, given we need the glosses "go", "excellent" and "kingdom"):

[image: over one]

And then to have the choice of either of the following (3 and 4, given we only need glosses for "go" and "kingdom"):

[image: over two]

[image: over three]

I was able to get some of the positioning ok using `display: relative` and then `position: absolute` on the `::after` but it required using a mix of hard-coded numbers of pixels (e.g, 25px) and percentages. Obviously with different sized fonts that isn't going to work and I didn't get all the options working either.

Basically, my question is - are all these variants going to be possible with `::after`? I can change to using elements if required, but having either `::after` or elements depending on what was chosen would require significant extra complexity in the generation code I'd rather avoid, so I would much rather doing all with either `::after` or all with elements.

1, 2 and 4 would be relatively easy if I rewrite to use elements but 3 seems pretty difficult either way.

Is there an elegant way to do all these with either of the options? Is there some other way?

Comment: I think it’s possible except I don’t understand how/why excellent was removed from 3 and 4. What is the algorithm for deciding to leave a word out completely? Also it’s always a help if you could include an example code of where you have got to so far.

Comment: @AHaworth, the question is very specifically about CSS presentation. As such, I included my current code for horizontal alignment at the top. I could put my attempts at vertical alignment but there were very many, none of which properly do any of the desired new options.

The choice of whether to gloss or not is separate, and the answer will likely span several chapters of my PhD thesis! I have updated the text, is that clearer?

Comment: There is no way to achieve this based on questions like "is it too long" in CSS. You are going to have to resort to Javascript to achieve this, and it's going to be ugly.

Comment: @connexo if you are sure about that, then if you create an answer I will mark it as the answer. If I need to resort to JS for 3 then that can come later if there is huge demand for it... Otherwise if there is an elegant way to do it with after, I'd love to know about it, otherwise I will convert my code to use elements instead of pure CSS.

Comment: I have suggested a method using just CSS and pseudo elements for option (3). Are the other options still unsolved?

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving verson (3) [i.e. the gloss being immediately above the characters with no movement of the basic text] would be to have the after element positioned absolutely, push it up by enough to clear the characters and back to the left by half its width and half the width of the underlying characters (i.e centered on the underlying characters).

None of this involves absolute units like px so it should be responsive to font size changes, although a slight guess has been taken at the height of the characters at a little over 1em.

```css
.tcrobe-word.tcrobe-gloss::after {
  content: ' ('attr(data-tcrobe-gloss) ')';
}

.option1 .tcrobe-word.tcrobe-gloss::after {
  vertical-align: 10%;
}

.option3 .tcrobe-word.tcrobe-gloss {
  position: relative;
}

.option3 .tcrobe-word.tcrobe-gloss::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.2em;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<h3>Option (1)</h3>
<div class="container option1">
  <span class="tcrobe-word tcrobe-gloss" data-tcrobe-gloss="go">前往</span>
  <span class="tcrobe-word tcrobe-gloss " data-tcrobe-gloss="excellent">前往</span>
  <span class="tcrobe-word tcrobe-gloss" data-tcrobe-gloss="kingdom">前往</span>
</div>
<h3>Option (3)</h3>
<div class="container option3">
  <span class="tcrobe-word tcrobe-gloss" data-tcrobe-gloss="go">前往</span> 前往
  <span class="tcrobe-word tcrobe-gloss" data-tcrobe-gloss="excellent">前往</span>
</div>
```

Note: I have a concern about accessibility. Screen readers may ignore content in pseudo elements so the alternative method mentioned in the question - with the gloss in the actual text - might be preferable.